# Unable to install ciso8601 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip, package

I have tried to do a `pip3 install ciso8601` on the Windows command prompt (I have Python 3.10 installed) but I can't help hitting this error message :

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfaqzmm6w'
       cwd: C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z81gigrv\ciso8601_18ea0de24a904fcdaeae094cf83a0854
```

And a bit further after a few lines of code verbose, there's this :

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ciso8601
Failed to build ciso8601
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ciso8601, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've looked for solutions online but I only read things about Visual C++ which version 14 is already installed on my computer.

Comment: My immediate assumption is that ciso8601 is not yet compatible with Python v3.10, so I took a look at their site. The [main page](https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601) shows only versions 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9 so despite having been tested with cPython 3.10, I'd assume you cannot yet use it with 3.10. If you look at their [release document](https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601/blob/master/RELEASING.md), it shows that support was added in v2.2.0 for Python v3.9, so it figures that you'll need to wait for an update.

Comment: `ciso8601` installed without error on Python 3.10.1 on Windows 10.